# Ignore tags <br/> in a tweet share

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I'm using a function to create a tweet text share:

```
 Social.prototype.shareTwitter = function() {
    var link = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=' + this.link + '&text=' + this.description  + '';

    window.location.href = link;
  };
```

And is working fine, but the problem is that in the `this.description` there are several br tags, and the twitter is understand as long spaces.

Is possible ignore the br tags??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the all br tags of description with string.empty ("")

```
this.description.replace(/(<br[^>]*>)/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will remove the `<br />` from the description :

```
Social.prototype.shareTwitter = function() {
    var link = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=' + this.link + '&text=' + this.description.replace(/(<br[^>]*>)/g, '')  + '';

    window.location.href = link;
};
```

Comment: I was late a minute with my post, but I believe this regex will only replace `<br/>` in first line. It needed `/g` option to replace it in all lines.